# Control matrix for a code

Tags: coding-theory

I got stuck in the following problem.

We recursively define the matrices for all $i\in \mathbb N$

$G_1 :=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

and $$G_{i+1} :=\begin{bmatrix}
G_i &G_i \\
0&J\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

for all $i\in \mathbb N$.

(a) Determine explicitly $G_2$ and $G_3$ and bring both to reduced row echelon form.

i. What (known) code does $G_2$ describe?

ii. Give a control matrix for $R_2$.

iii. $R_3$ is equivalent to the $(8, 4)$ Bauer code.

(b) Prove by induction:

$R_i$ contains the words 0 and 1. All other code words have the weight 2i-1.

Comment: What is $J{}{}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: the matrix whose entries all one.

Comment: i tried to bild a control matrix,but i has not been successful.

Comment: your question is imprecise in that the term "control matrix" is not standard in coding theory. Neither does your question define what $R_i$ is.